# checkboxes checked by default from string or array values

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I'm building a submit form that can be edited after the fact and have a series of checkboxes that submit to an array but when I edit the data I'd like to have the boxes previously selected checked already.  When the form is initially submitted the checkboxes all go into an array that gets implode to be put into a single cell in the database.  This is what I have so far.

```
<?php
$query  = "SELECT * FROM profile WHERE username = '{$_SESSION['username']}' ";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if (!$result) {
    $_SESSION["message"] = "You have not built your profile yet.";
    redirect_to("my_profile.php");
} 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$activities   = $row['activities'];
?>  


<fieldset>  
     <legend>What kind of activities do you enjoy?</legend><br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="activities[]" value="sailing"/>Sailing
     <input type="checkbox" name="activities[]" value="hiking"/>Hiking
     <input type="checkbox" name="activities[]" value="gaming"/>Gaming<br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="activities[]" value="mountain_biking"/>Mountain Biking
     <input type="checkbox" name="activities[]" value="food"/>Food
     <input type="checkbox" name="activities[]" value="travel"/>Travel<br />
     <input type="checkbox" name="activities[]" value="paintball"/>Paintball
<input type="checkbox" name="activities[]" value="computers"/>Computers
</fieldset>
```

Comment: your logic is bad. a query which returns no rows is **NOT** a failure. it's a perfectly valid query result which happens to have no rows. mysqli_query returns either a result handle, or boolean false. and boolean false only ever gets returned on a REAL failure. e.g. sql syntax error, communications error, blah blah blah.

Comment: `explode() $activities` and then use something like `if(in_array('sailing', $activities)) { echo 'checked'; }`

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly for what I wanted. and @MarcB Thanks I hadn't noticed that little mistake there I will fix it.